# Has Don Lancaster really got his "Create Sinewaves using Digital IC's" publication wrong?

Tags: digital-logic, sine

I answered [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613551/generate-a-120-degrees-out-of-phase-sine-wave) question a moment ago, and looked around for some stuff on the net to support it.

The original publication is "Digital Generation of Low Frequency Sinewaves", Anthony C Davis, IEEE Transactions on Instrumentation and Measurement, June 1969 pp97-105. Here's a [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4313775) but unfortunately it's paywalled.

Don Lancaster produced a [publication](https://www.tinaja.com/glib/rad_elec/digital_sinewaves_11_76.pdf) referencing it. This is the only one I've been able to find.

In his Table 1, giving resistor values for generators of various lengths, for the 5 resistors for the /12 use case of my answer, he produces the exact values of 1.000, 1.732, 2.000 and then finds close resistor values in some standard series.

The problem is that these exact numbers appear to be the conductance values that one should use, and you need to use the reciprocal to find the resistors.

Am I going mad, have I got it the wrong way round? I've built this circuit using my method of computing them, and it works. How can a publication like this have got it wrong for so long? I can't find any correction, retraction or update. Are there any that I've missed? Are there any publications that get it right? I'm curious as to what Davis' original publication said, if anybody has access to it and can comment.

Comment: Since the point of the magic sinewaves was to have a purely digital means of doing it, perhaps the author added the analog equivalent as an afterthought without scrutinizing it. The important bit is digital, and I presume nobody looked at that article with an analog implementation in mind. I'm sure that if you write Don, he may well fix it, after all those years :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I'm sure his publication predates the Magic Sinewaves all digital version by some considerable time. Perhaps it's just been forgotten in the light of magic sinewaves and cheap DDS, DACs and MCUs.

Answer (score 3):

The original paper labels the resistors in terms of **conductance**, as you suggest:

[image]

Looks like an error. I wonder how bad the 'sine wave' is when built with the incorrect values. Working into a non-zero load resistance is also not great.

There was a long time during which it was possible for an author eke out a living by taking "hard to get" information such as data sheets (yes, they were hard for hobbyists and tinkerers and even small businesses to get) and IEEE papers, massage the data a bit and present it to the masses in publications for a fixed number of pennies per word.

Comment: That diagram is from the Davis paper? Is there a non-paywalled version available anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it's from the original paper. You can find it [here](https://am.booksc.eu/book/14609321/40f122) but I'm not sure how legitimate that link is.