# Tips on Building An Analog VCO

Tags: amplifier, frequency, vco

I am attempting to build an analog VCO. Many of the resources I see online implement a 555 timer, but I am trying to avoid that, solely for the sake of learning how to do this in purely analog. Here is the general setup of my situation:

I have a feedback system with an integrator and a comparator, turning square waves into triangle waves and triangle waves into square waves. I want to use the increasing and decreasing voltages from the ramps of the triangles to generate a sine wave with corresponding frequency. Then, as I move up the ramp of the triangle, I should see sine waves appear with more frequency. My hope is to generate signals with frequencies in the range 1-3kHz.

The next part of this problem is generating the final sine wave. I found a paper online using the following closed feedback circuit:

[image]

I have found that, by varying R6 from 2000 Ohms to 250 Ohms, I can generate those frequencies. However, to implement this design, I would need to be able to vary the resistance of R6 between those values by using the triangle wave mentioned previously. That is, I need a voltage-controlled resistor, whose maximum resistance corresponds to the maximum of my triangle and likewise for the minimum (or maybe vice-versa? It's possible I have that backwards). I have looked into using JFETs to achieve this, but the attempts I have made have not worked. Is this a reliable way to achieve what I am trying to do? If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by _analog_, if you somewhat arbitrarily want to exclude the 555 timer but then go on to build a circuit with comparators.

Comment: There are sooooo many ways to skin that cat. A real analogue VCO would use sinewaves throughout, of which a Wein bridge, and a state-variable oscillator are perhaps the two most popular. Reconstructing sinewaves from triangle waves is possible, but prone to high distortion, and is almost never done these days, as it gives no real advantages. But it's an interesting learning exercise in analogue design. Be clearer about where you want to spend your time and learning energy.

Comment: The site frowns on 'link only' answers, so I'm going to make a link only comment. You might try these for inspiration https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613551/generate-a-120-degrees-out-of-phase-sine-wave and https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa665c/snoa665c.pdf

Comment: So, my issue is not converting a triangle wave to a sine wave. In fact, I have gotten around that by trying to construct this voltage-controlled resistor. That is where the issue lies, though. Am I on the right track trying to use JFETs?